# Entropy increase due to particle decay

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, entropy

The entropy density of the Universe is given by 
$$s(T)=\frac{\rho+P}{T}$$
Why can decaying particles, which have decoupled from the photons, increase the entropy? The decay cannot change $\rho$ because it only redistributes the energy... According to my understanding the decay can only increase the entropy of the "photon fluid" by transferring the freed binding energy as heat but not the entropy of the whole Universe. What do I get wrong?

Comment: can you give a link for the definition of the formula? If one goes to the statistial definition of entropy which counts number of microstates there is no problem, since decays add extra microstates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy

Comment: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/Cosmology/Chapter3.pdf (page 56)

Comment: Thanks. Ι cannot help you find the discrepancy. I am sure that at a basic counting of microstates  decays increase the entropy, but the link is making a large number of assumptions to reach the formula, and I am not familiar with the formalism.

Comment: Ok but thank you anyway.

Comment: "Since there are far more photons
than baryons in the universe, the entropy of the universe is dominated by the entropy of the
photon bath (at least as long as the universe is sufficiently
uniform). Any entropy production
from non-equilibrium processes is therefore total insignificant relative to the total entropy", so they are not considering particles other than photons, which do not decay.

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams  the quote from the link?

Comment: @annav a little above the equation in the article the OP  linked

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams yes, but also further on it is discussing neutron decays etc .

Comment: @annav ops, you are right. Then I do not know!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to consider any photon field to see that particle decay is an entropy-increasing process.  Consider a two-body decay like $\pi^+\to\mu^+\nu_\mu$.  The pion doesn't have any spin, and in its rest frame it doesn't have any momentum --- so the pion believes that its entropy is zero.  After the decay, there are many possible orientations for the back-to-back $\mu^+\nu_\mu$ pair, which therefore has an entropy that's greater than zero.

If I'm reading your link correctly, your expression is for the total entropy density of a hot early universe at equilibrium. Critically, it assumes that there are many more photons than other species of particle, and so the photons contain "all" of the entropy.
That approximation is useful for making predictions about the evolution of the universe, but it's not useful for making pedagogical statements about entropy, as you have discovered.